# How to add <br /> to wordpress widget title?

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm trying to add `<br />` code to widget titles in Wordpress, as most of my widget's titles are on two lines, and I would like to format the text so it makes more sense to the reader.

I've tried a few different suggested solutions, including adding various code to the Functions file:

```
    add_filter('widget_title', 'change_widget_title', 10, 3);
    function change_widget_title($title, $instance, $wid){
    return $title = str_replace('Widget Title', '<span style="color: red">Custom</span>', $title);
    }
```

That didn't work for me unfortunately.

Nor did #4 on this page:
http://www.rvamedia.com/wordpress/customize-wordpress-widget-title

I don't even need the title to link to anything, I just want to put in a `<br />` so it'll show properly on two lines.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: where do you need add the `<br />` in the title? like, after specific number of words?

Comment: I have nine different widgets on the homepage, so the position of the `<br />` would vary for each one unfortunately.

Comment: Why don't you collect the titls into an array (e.g. `$titles = array('Widget title one', 'Widget title two', 'Widget title three');`) and then use php implode function to glue the array elements with `<br />` like this: `$new_title = implode('<br />', $titles);`

Comment: Each widget has a separate title e.g. "Diggers, Dumpers, Dozers, Rollers & Loaders" and another is called "Self Drive & Spider Booms". So in the first one, I'd want the `<br />` after 'Dumpers' and the second after the ampersand. Is this possible using your solution?

Comment: What you need the use of `wordwrap()` function in PHP, take a look at http://php.net/manual/en/function.wordwrap.php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I know its a little late for the answer but may be it will help others
Its very simple, You can get help from shortcode by

```
    add_filter('widget_title', 'do_shortcode');

function line_break() {
    return '<br />';
}

add_shortcode('br', 'line_break');
```

Put this in your `functions.php` file at the end than use `<br/>` as shortcode i.e. `br`

Answer (score 1):

I figured out an alternative to this issue.

Instead of putting a br in the widget title, I put the first line of the title as the title, and then inserted a div with the same background color and text color at the very top of the text widget that had the second line.

You can then style this div to have the same qualities as the widget title e.g. no underline, no text transform, etc. to make it look the exact same as the widget title.